# Help solving third-order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this 3rd order non h ode.

$$
x^3y'''-3x^2y''+6xy'-6y=2x^4e^x
$$

But im stuck after solving the homogeneous

$
x^3y'''-3x^2y''+6xy'-6y=0
$

With $y=e^a$ for $a=kx$

My output was $k^3x^3-k^2 3x^2+k6x-6=0$

But Im not sure how to follow up since I dont usually have functions of x before the differentials.

EDIT: Ok I solved the homo transforming $y(x) = u(lnx)$

result was $y(x)=ax+bx^2+cx^3$.

What method should I use for getting the particular solution?

Comment: This is an Euler type ODE. The relevant solution class is $y=x^\lambda$. Or set $x=e^t$ to transform the ODE into a standard linear ODE with constant coefficients.

Comment: Show that $$x,x^2,x^3$$ are solutions of the homogenious part like the ansatz written above

Comment: DO you mean replace x with $$e^t$$ at the very beginning?? @LutzL

Comment: Yes. Of course everywhere. Which means to substitute $u(t)=y(e^t)$ or equivalently $y(x)=u(\ln(x))$ and compute the derivatives via chain rule..